# How do I get grub's name for a given partition? (specifically grub2)

Tags: grub2

I know that grub names my hard drives and partitions counting from zero, so `/dev/sda` *might* be `(hd0,0)` and `/dev/sdb2` *might* be `(hd1,2)`. Is it guaranteed that grub numbers the hard drives in the same order that Linux does, or even the partitions, for that matter? The documentation that I found<sup>(1)</sup> for this naming convention handwaves over this detail, and I can't find a way to actually determine what grub's name for a given partition will be.

I was under the impression that it isn't even *guaranteed* that `/dev/sda` won't load as `/dev/sdc` when I reboot my PC, and that this is why we use UUID's in `fstab` instead of `/dev/sd*` labels. Is there a way to use a UUID or something similar in `/etc/grub.d` scripts, instead of the `(hdX,Y)` notation?

(1) https://dev.gentoo.org/~floppym/grub.html#Naming-convention

Comment: What do you need the name for? What operation will you do with it?

Comment: Well, the devices list is repopulated at every start... So `/dev/sda` will always be `(hd0)`, but it might be that the BIOS sends in different order the disk list, and so what was `(hd0)` on one start is `(hd1)` on the next. *If* the master/slave options are set correctly in the disk jumpers, what *should* happen is that `master` is always presented by the motherboard first, while the slaves should follow the order of the cables. It might be that your motherboard tweak some of these options, so you should really have a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

- *"/dev/sda might be (hd0,0)"* : wrong. Disks are represented by a single number by GRUB. If GRUB is installed in /dev/sda, it will be `(hd0)`.
- Partitions are name with `(hdX,Y)`, with `X` being the hard drive number and `Y` the partition number.
- Disk numbers vary from case to case. If you chainloaded GRUB in another disk (say, a thumb drive), the thumb drive will be represented as `(hd0)` and your main disk as `(hd1)` (the opposite happens if you run GRUB from your main disk).
- You can always list all the drives in GRUB using the `ls` command.
- You can use UUIDs instead of the traditional `(hdx,y)` method with this command: `search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set XXXXXX` (replacing `XXXXXX` with your partition's UUID. It will set it as the root.

Comment: my grub is actually installed in /dev/sdb, so I guess that will always be (hd0) to grub and /dev/sda will be (hd1)?

Comment: after looking around in the grub terminal, `(hd0)` is an inaccessible drive without any partitions (that doesn't actually exist, I only have two hard disk drives), `/dev/sdb` (the drive that grub is loaded on) was `(hd1)` -- not `(hd0)`, and `/dev/sda` was actually `(hd2)`